Cost minimisation for the production function $f(L,K) = L^\lambda + K^\gamma$
For the function: $f(L,K) = L^\lambda + K^\gamma $. The value for $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ is not given.

What type of production function is this (quasi-linear, CES)?
Is it true for there to be diminishing MRTS, $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ has to be between 0 and 1?
I am trying to minimise the cost for inputs L and K to produce q quantity of output, is it possible to do so with this function via lagrangian multiplier? I have tried to do so but the derivations ended up being too complicated.


Welcome to Economics SE! Please note that we do have a policy on homework questions that requires you to demonstrate reasonable effort, which includes your own attempt(s) at a solution as well as properly formatting the post using Markdown and MathJax.

A closed form solution does not exist. Unless the value for lambda and gamma is specified. Cost minimisation is not possible.

This answer is not correct.
